# JSX render method in react

Tags: javascript, performance, html, react.js, jsx

Following is the piece of code which is working fine, but somehow it looks bit odd to me to have a function inside a render method and using it in both conditions. Let me know how can I improve this react code as `showContainer` is only adding a wrapper to the function JSX.

Code -

```
render () {

  const childJsx = () => (<><h3>Random Child JSX</h3></>)

  return (
            <>
            { showContainer ?
             <Modal>
                {childJsx()}
             </Modal>
             :
             <div className="parent">
                {childJsx()}
             </div>
            } 
            </>
        )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `functional`method is fine, just the place You have defined is a bit anti pattern. (But well, if you really want to use that component in JUST in that scope its still fine.)

But let me try to refactor it in  a react way:

```
render () {

  return (
            <>
            {
              showContainer
                ? (
                  <Modal>
                    <ChildJsx />
                  </Modal>
                )
                : (
                  <div className="parent">
                    <ChildJsx />
                  </div>
                )
            } 
            </>
        )
}

function ChildJsx(props){
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Random Child JSX</h3>
    </>
  )
}
```

React is about **reusability**. In this case you can use that small component again and again as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain this `You have defined is a bit anti pattern` . How can i remove this ?

Comment: `just the place You have defined is a bit anti pattern` means that you have defined a fully functional component inside a `React.Component`. You can have the reason to define it right there, but havent seend that context. If you have no a specific reason to define it in that scope, its better to separate it in a new `functional` component.(Because of reusability)

Comment: @Peter React key is completely unnecessary in this case, they are only required (and useful) when rendering arrays. [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) I also completely disagree with defining functions that return JSX within a component being an anti-pattern, it is very common in fact to do this. Even functional components can be defined and used this way. The only real reason to externalize them is if you *want* to reuse them in other components, otherwise, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: @DrewReese As I said, if you have a reason to define a function inside a component, lets do that. But im pretty sure your wrapper is pretty fine as a standalone component. And sooner or later in a bigger project that will be a standalone component.

Comment: @DrewReese `The only real reason to externalize them is if you want to reuse them in other components, otherwise, this is perfectly valid` React is about reuasbility. You should HAVE a reason to not externalise the components

Comment: @Peter Yes, it's called scope. You should always limit the scope of defined variables as much as is reasonably possible. It's the same reason you don't define all your variables globally. Anyway, the comment was with regards to your assumption it was an anti-pattern which you, oddly enough, later indirectly say it is *actually* ok. It can't be both anti-pattern and pattern.

Comment: Second line was directly said that

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally select the wrapper instead. Use the ternary to create an internal wrapper component. Not much of a code reduction though, but rather just moving the logic a bit. You can also remove the react Fragments as all the returns are returning single react nodes, which *does* help reduce the code and IMO improve readability.

```
render() {
  const childJsx = () => <h3>Random Child JSX</h3>;

  const Wrapper = showContainer
    ? ({ children }) => <Modal>{children}</Modal>
    : ({ children }) => <div className="parent">{children}</div>;

  return <Wrapper>{childJsx()}</Wrapper>;
}
```

*Note: all internally defined render functions or functional components can be defined externally if you desire to use elsewhere in other components.*

Answer (score 0):

While Drew and Peter provide some useful techniques when dealing with complex components, this case cries out for the simplest solution possible.

```
render () {
    if (showContainer) {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <h3>Random Child JSX</h3>
            </Modal>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <h3>Random Child JSX</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Why would I start with this where there's so much repeated code? Simplicity is the first step in refactoring. Once you've simplified the problem, you can easily spot where you can make further refactorings once things grow in complexity. As written, this takes only a few seconds to read and understand—something you'll do far more often than writing.